# HTML Tables & Automated Email Response with Forms

Tags: html, forms, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to fix a form and it doesn't seem to be cooperating. It was originally done in HTML tables and because of the old structure of the website I manage (it's an internal only), I'm having a difficult time trying to see where my problem lies.

Issue: There's a form created for Key requests for desks and cabinets, etc. The automated e-mail response after the form fill is coming through with a message to reply to an email dress that is no longer valid. I've updated the HTML version of the form, along with the fields of the form processor and the e-mail is still coming up to say "To approve - reply to : lebarbe@example.org". It should say "To approve - reply to: rolandjordan@example.org".

I've attached copies of the confirmation e-mail, the HTML form, and screenshots of the form processor. Can anyone help me understand what needs to change?
Here's the E-Mailed response that generates to the Department Director:

```
Received : 1/18/2017 10:48:48 AM
Form : Key and Lock Request Form
Submission ID : 27715
User IP : 
______________________
NOTE :
A key and lock request has been made for your department by the person listed below. To approve, you must reply to this email.                                

Task : Keys Made
Key Number : 1234
Quantity of Keys Needed : 7
Lock Number : 1234
Current Lock Combination :
Location : Marketing
Justification :
Comments : Test - do not process
Requestor Name : Kara Kentner
TM Number : 1234
Title : Webmaster
Department : Marketing
Phone Extension : 7214
Cost Center :
Access Control Request :
Access Area Requested To :
                                                       :
FOR KEYS THAT OPEN DEPARTMENTS OR OFFICES :
Key Issued To :
Team Member Number :
                                                    :
DIRECTOR INFORMATION :
Director : Kara Kentner
Email : kjkentner@example.org
To approve - reply to : lebarbe@example.org
```

The last part is what needs changed. The email also comes from the email address lebarbe@example.org and it should come from rolandjorand@example.org.  I've updated this section of the HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="To approve - reply to" value="rolandjordan@example.org">
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>EJGH Team Talk</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.heading {font:bold 1.4em Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif; color:#333;}
.title {font:11px Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;}
.text {font:11px Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#2A6BA5;}
.text:hover { font:11px Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#2A6BA5; text-decoration: none }
.copytext {font:11px Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-weight:normal; color:#333;}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body >
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="16">
  <form name="KeyRequest" method="POST" action="http://teamtalk.net/absolutefp/afp.asp?formid=22">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="copytext"><table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" colspan="4" valign="top" class="copytext"><span class="text">Key and Lock Request Printable Form</span><br>
                <span class="text">Note</span>: To save form to your computer, Right click on icon and select <span class="text">Save Target As...</span><br>
                                 <br>
                                 <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
                                   <tr bgcolor="#666666">
                                     <td width="56%" bgcolor="#666666" class="title">Name</td>
                                     <td width="21%" bgcolor="#666666" class="title"><div align="center">Adobe PDF Format</div></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                     <td class="copytext" width="56%" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Key and Lock Request Printable Form</td>
                                     <td class="copytext" width="21%" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><div align="center"><a href="KeyRequest.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/pdf-logo.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a></div></td>
                                   </tr>
                                 </table>
            <br>
                                 <br>
                                 <span class="text">Key and Lock Request Online Form</span><br>
                                 <span class="text">Note: </span>Fields marked with an asterisk(*) are required.<br>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="NOTE" value="A key and lock request has been made for your department by the person listed below. To approve, you must send your reply to rolandjordan@example.org.                                 ">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text"><table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"  style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#666666" class="title">Task (<strong>Please select all</strong> that apply:) *</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="4%" class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Task" type="checkbox" class="text" value="Keys Made"></td>
              <td width="96%" class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Keys made</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Task" type="checkbox" class="text" value="Lock Changed"></td>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Lock changed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Task" type="checkbox" class="text" value="Push button lock combination changed"></td>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Push button lock combination changed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Task" type="checkbox" class="text" value="Padlock removed"></td>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Padlock removed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Task" type="checkbox" class="text" value="Padlock installed"></td>
              <td class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">Padlock installed</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            <br>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
              <tr class="title">
                <td width="14%" bgcolor="#666666" align="center" class="title">Key #</td>
                <td width="13%" bgcolor="#666666" align="center" class="title">Quantity of Keys Needed</td>
                <td width="13%" bgcolor="#666666" align="center" class="title">Lock #</td>
                <td width="18%" bgcolor="#666666" align="center" class="title">Current Lock Combination</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="text" align="center" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;"><input name="Key Number" type="text" class="copytext" id="Key Number" size="8" maxlength="10"></td>
                <td valign="top" class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" align="center">
                  <select name="Quantity of Keys Needed" class="copytext" id="Quantity of Keys Needed">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
     </td>
                <td valign="top" class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" align="center">
                  <input name="Lock Number" type="text" class="copytext" id="Lock Number" size="8" maxlength="10">
    </td>
                <td valign="top" class="text" style="border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;" align="center">
                  <input name="Current Lock Combination" type="text" class="copytext" id="Current Lock Combination" size="12" maxlength="15">
    </td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text"><span class="text">Location: * </span></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="text"><input name="Location" type="text" class="copytext" id="Location" size="87" maxlength="200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text">Justification:</td>
          <td colspan="3" class="text"><input name="Justification" type="text" class="copytext" id="Justification2" size="30" maxlength="200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="text">Comments:</td>
          <td colspan="3" class="text"><textarea name="Comments" cols="89" rows="6" class="copytext" id="Comments"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" valign="top" class="text">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap class="text">Requestor Name: *</td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Requestor Name" type="text" class="copytext" id="Requestor Name" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
          <td class="text">TM Number: * </td>
          <td class="text"><input name="TM Number" type="text" class="copytext" id="TM Number" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text">Title: *</td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Title" type="text" class="copytext" id="Title" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
          <td nowrap class="text">Department: *</td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Department" type="text" class="copytext" id="Department" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap class="text">Phone Extension: *</td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Phone Extension" type="text" class="copytext" id="Phone Extension" size="30" maxlength="15"></td>
          <td class="text">Cost Center: </td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Cost Center" type="text" class="copytext" id="Cost Center" size="30" maxlength="200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap class="text">Access Control Request: </td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Access Control Request" type="text" class="copytext" id="Access Control Request" size="30" maxlength="200"></td>
          <td class="text">Access Area Requested To: </td>
          <td class="text"><input name="Access Area Requested To" type="text" class="copytext" id="Access Area Requested To" size="30" maxlength="200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#666666" class="title"><input type="hidden" name="                                                      "><input type="hidden" name="FOR KEYS THAT OPEN DEPARTMENTS OR OFFICES">For Keys That Open Departments Or Offices (Does not apply to keys for desks, file cabinets, etc.)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="19%" class="text">Key Issued To (Name): </td>
              <td width="81%" class="copytext"><input name="Key Issued To" type="text" class="copytext" size="50" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text">TM Number: </td>
              <td class="text"><input name="Team Member Number" type="text" class="copytext" size="50" maxlength="100" id="Team Member Number"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="copytext"><span style="color: #FF0000"><strong>NOTE:</strong></span> <em>This may be the same person as the requestor. A separate request is required for each individual receiving key(s). Requests for multiple copies of&nbsp;the same key&nbsp;for one person will be denied.</em></td>
              </tr>
            </table>          
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#666666" class="title"><input type="hidden" name="                                                   "><input type="hidden" name="DIRECTOR INFORMATION">
                Director Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="19%" class="text">Dept. Director: *</td>
              <td width="81%" class="text"><input name="Director" type="text" class="copytext" size="50" maxlength="100">
                <span class="text" style="color: #FF0000">DEPARTMENT DIRECTOR ONLY</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text">Dept. Director Email: *</td>
              <td class="text"><input name="Email" type="text" class="copytext" size="50" maxlength="100">
                <span class="text" style="color: #FF0000">DEPARTMENT DIRECTOR'S EMAIL ONLY</span>
              <input type="hidden" name="To approve - reply to" value="rolandjordan@example.org"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="text">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="text" style="color: #FF0000">NOTE: <span class="text" style="color: #FF0000">Request will be emailed to the Department Director first for approval.</span></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="copytext">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="copytext"><p align="left">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="copytext">
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" class="copytext">
          </p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it still is not coming through correctly. I've also cleared my cache and restarted my browser, just as a last resort. To no avail.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for editing my post - however in order to remove our table tags, we'd need to re-do the entire Intranet site and that is not a priority for our administration yet. I'm aware it's archaic but I have to manage for right now. So because of that, I have to work within my limitations which are shown above. If you could give me any tips on how to fix the problem, that would be great.

Comment: So the issue is that there's a "from emailadress" you dont know where is set?

Comment: Essentially, yes - But if you look in the code it's shown there - it's just not updating in the form itself. I've cached, etc. Still nothing. A, I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: there must be some code that sent the mail out, its it through php?